# Reading in raw files C++

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

How is data stored when read in using `fstream class`? An example will clarify my question:

```
    char * memBlock = NULL;
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    memBlock = **new** char[fileSize];
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    file.read(memBlock, fileSize);
    file.close();

    if(memBlock)
    return memBlock;
```

The context is that I am reading a raw image that has been recorded in hex so that

- the values representing the pixels are either 00 or ff (black or white, 1 or 0)
- and are arranged in columns and rows.

When reading the file in memory, are the values in the `memblock array` stored as ff and 00 or are they converted into 1 and 0 automatically by ASCII or something?

Comment: A lot of things are not making sense here. A raw image is binary data. Binary data can be viewed in hex, but not converted to hex. This is only possible with text-data. Was your image converted to a text-file?

Comment: thnx for the edits, srry about the awkward language what I was meaning to say was if presented with ff which is stored as 11111111 in memory is there a way for me to convert this to char = '1' using printf(some specifier, param)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the data is stored as hex

```
00FF00FF
```

and you read it using `file.read` as shown in your code, 
then it is stored as that, which means  that

```
memcmp(memblock, "00FF00FF", 8) == 0
```

will evaluate to true.

**EDIT**

You have to make the conversion yourself. One way would be

```
int ConvertToColor(const char *colorBuffer, size_t size)
{
    int color = -1;
    if(size >= 2)
    {
        char colorCode[3] = { colorBuffer[0], colorBuffer[1], 0 };
        long longColor = strtol(colorCode, NULL, 16);
        if(longColor != LONG_MAX && longColor != LONG_MIN)            
            color = (int)longColor;

    } 
    return color;   
}

std::vector<int> ConvertToColors(const char *memBlock, size_t size)
{
    std::vector<int> colors;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
    {
        int color = ConvertToColor(memBlock + i, size - i);
        if(color < 0)
            throw std::exception("Unable to convert color.");
        colors.push_back(color ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return colors;
}
```

Comment: ok so if my program expects to take in an array of 1's and 0's i need to parse the 00 and ff data to equal 1 and 0 (in place of 00 or ff) is there a function that will automatically do that for me when i read in the raw data or do I have to create my own.

Comment: @user1084113: Since that's a rather bizzare translation, you'll have to do something yourself. When you say your program expects an arrays of 1s and 0s, do you mean an array of '1' and '0' characters, chars holding 1 or 0, or raw binary?

Answer (score 0):

For reading raw data file, first you have to open your files in binary mode, which is not the default for `fstream`. Use `file.open(filename, std::ios::binary|std::ios::in)`.

In this way, the content which is read into the memory buffer will be exactly the same as file content.

So if you have `00ff00ff` in the file, you will have `00ff00ff` in your memory. There will be no conversion.

If you want to convert it to `0`'s and `1`'s, assuming with `00ff00ff`, you mean each byte is `0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff`, you can do the following conversion : (if the `00ff00ff` are in fact eight ASCII characters, see esskar's answer)

```
for (size_t i=0; i<fileSize; i++)
{
    if (memBlock[i]!=0) memBlock[i]=1;
    // or
    // memBlock[i] &= 1;
}
```

This will convert the buffer into a serials of binary `0` and `1` bytes.